# QSqlQueryModel prepared statement (using QSqlQuery) not working

Tags: postgresql, qt5, qsqlquery

I have a problem using QSqlQueryModel with prepared statement. When executing the statement manually everything works fine, but when binding it to the model - it doesn't execute. On the other hand when I set the model with a "static" query (via QString) - the model executes and loades the data. What am I doing wrong?

I prepere the query like this:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare(QString("SELECT \
        kontrahentid \
        , trim(format ('%s %s %s', kontrahentnazwafirmy, kontrahentnazwisko, kontrahentimie) ) as nazwa \
    FROM kontrahent \
    WHERE %1 ilike ? \
").arg(searchBy));
query.addBindValue(searchString);
```

And it works when querying like this:

```
if (query.exec()) {
    while (query.next()) {
        qDebug() << "{" << query.value(0) << ", " << query.value(1) << "}";
    }
}
```

In postgres log I have prepare statement, and executing it the moment after.
But when binding it to the model it doesn't work:

```
QSqlQueryModel* model = new QSqlQueryModel(this);
model->setQuery(query);
//model->setQuery("SELECT kontrahentid, trim(format ('%s %s %s', kontrahentnazwafirmy, kontrahentnazwisko, kontrahentimie) ) as nazwa FROM kontrahent");
if (model->lastError().isValid()) {
    qDebug() << model->lastError();
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); ++i) {
    //int id = model.record(i).value("id").toInt();
    //QString name = model.record(i).value("name").toString();
    qDebug() << model->record(i).value(0) << model->record(i).value(1);
}
```

In postgres log I only have the prepare statement, no sign of executing... But when uncommenting the line with "static" query (and commenting the one above it) it works all fine...

What am I doing wrong? do i have to run execute() on the query object before binding it to the model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> do i have to run execute() on the query object before binding it to
>   the model?

Yes. The doc for [QSqlQueryModel::setQuery(const QSqlQuery & query)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#setQuery) says:

> Note that the query **must be active** and must not be
>   isForwardOnly().

For a query to be active, it must has been executed. The doc for [QSqlQuery](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquery.html) says:

> Successfully executed SQL statements set the query's state to active
>   so that isActive() returns true. Otherwise the query's state is set to
>   inactive. In either case, when executing a new SQL statement, the
>   query is positioned on an invalid record. An active query must be
>   navigated to a valid record (so that isValid() returns true) before
>   values can be retrieved.

Comment: Yup - that was it... I thought that if QSqlQueryModel executes the "static" query itself, it should do the same with prepared one... Pity that such an example is missing in QSqlQueryModel doc... Thanks!